# Self expiring object - any better alternative

Tags: java

Please find below the class that I have created and intend to use as a self-expiring object.

```
public class SelfExpiringObject {

    private boolean expired;
    // other properties

    public void setValidity(final int seconds) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                expired = true;
            }
        }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return expired;
    }
}
```

Any better alternative that anybody can suggest?

Want to use this in a rule engine for processing events. One of the scenarios would be when the events are received, they are put into the session (using object with self-expiring property). I want them to be in the session only as per the validity set up in the rules. Once they expire, they would be removed from the session.

Comment: You could maybe use [guava's CacheBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) which has an auto-expiry parameter?

Comment: Yes, but in that case I will have to put the object in the cache. I am using Drools where I need to put/load the objects in its session.

Comment: I am no JAVA dev, but Shirley, this would create a tonne of Timer objects. Have you considered a simple `DateTime` field (which on construction is set to 10 seconds in the future for example) and a comparison to `DateTime.Now` at `IsExpired()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each Timer creates a thread and this is a very expensive object.  I suggest you just have the expiry time in the object and have a thread which periodically removes expired objects.

```
public class ExpiringObject {

    private long expiresMS;
    // other properties

    public void setValidity(final int seconds) {
        expiresMS = System.currentTimeMillis() + seconds * 1000;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() >= expireMS;
    }
}
```

The thread which monitors these items can update Drools when it has expired.

Comment: This is one of the options that I may consider.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Note: the monitoring thread can perform any action you need when an expiry has been reached.

Comment: Using this code, but instead of using a monitor thread, just decided to use isExpired() method directly in the rules' file.   Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Just calculate the expiry lazily:

```
private long expiryDate; // set in constructor

public boolean isExpired() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() >= expiryDate;
}
```

No need to spawn a thread.

Comment: I want to check if the object has expired during rules' execution. Please consider the following sample rule-   rule "some rule"
when
    $event : Event (expired == false)
then
    modify( $event ) { setRetainTime( 60 ) };
end

Comment: Nice one - You should probably use `System.nanotime()` to calculate delays.

Comment: beat me by 40 seconds ;-)

Comment: @Sudhanshu You can access a property in DRL in the normal way - you don't need a field called `expired` if you have a method called `isExpired()`

Answer (score 4):

The [Apache Collections PassiveExpiringMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.html) could worth looking at.

Comment: Cannot put objects into the map. They are loaded in Drools session.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a timer, you could simply use timestamps:

```
public class SelfExpiringObject {
    private long timestamp;

    private boolean expired;
    // other properties

    public void setValidity(final int seconds) {
        timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * seconds;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        if (!expired) {
            expired = System.currentTimeMillis() >= timestamp;
        } 
        return expired;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case I have to call isExpired() to update that flag. As given below, I want to use this in a .drl (rules) file.

Answer (score 2):

- If you have many events, creating one Timer per event is not going to be very efficient.
- `ScheduledExecutor` tend to be more robust.
- Your code is not thread safe and a code calling `isExpired` after the Timer has run might still see `false` - the simplest thing is to mark the variable `volatile`

So your class could look like this (although I prefer the other proposed approach to remove the threads completely and use timestamps instead):

```
public class SelfExpiringObject {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private volatile boolean expired = false;
    // other properties

    public SelfExpiringObject(ScheduledExecutorService scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void setValidity(final int seconds) {
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                expired = true;
            }
        }, seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return expired;
    }
}
```

To create a ScheduledExecutorService:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
```

Comment: This is something that I may try, this will also help in controlling the number of threads (that can be) spawn. The code would be called by Drools engine.